# Merge these array values into a new array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge, array-map

I have the following array stored in `$data`

```
Array
(
    [name] => JimBob
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2013-15-5
                    [pole] => 2
                    [race] => 43
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2013-15-6
                    [pole] => 15
                    [race] => 34
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 2013-15-7
                    [pole] => 9
                    [race] => 54
                )

        )

)
```

I need to create a new array which looks like this

```
Array
(
    [name] => JimBob
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-15-5,2
            [1] => 2013-15-6,15
            [2] => 2013-15-7,9
        )

)
```

So far I have this array_map function

```
$arr2['data'] = array_map(function($date) {
    return $date['date'];
}, $data['data']);

print_r($arr2);
```

Which outputs the below, how can I get the pole values added to these dates separated by comma?

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-15-5
            [1] => 2013-15-6
            [2] => 2013-15-7
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use concatenation.

```
$arr2['data'] = array_map(function($date) {
    return $date['date'] . ',' . $date['pole'];
}, $data['data']);
```